# Installing PlatformToolset v110 without installing Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

We have a Visual Studio solution that contains some VC++ projects, and we've currently upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 from VS2010. In the process we also lifted the VC++ projects to PlatformToolset v110.

On our build server (Jenkins), we would like to build this project with MsBuild without having to install VS2012. But I can't get it to work, and I think it's because the folder **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110** must be present.

This folder and its contents is created during installation of VS2012, but as far as I can tell it won't be included in either the Windows SDK 7.1 or Windows SDK 8.0?

Is there any other SDK or installation package that can help with this issue?

Comment: Just out of interest, why don't you want to install VS2012? We migrated ok from VS2008 on our build system and have both environments working together.

Comment: The reasons are for licensing costs and convenience, it seems like an overkill to install the full VS2012 on each Jenkins slave if it's not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know it's not *really* without installing Visual Studio 2012, but:

If licensing costs are the biggest driver perhaps the [Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop) edition could be an alternative. You could keep the installation to the minimum required to support C++ builds.

Comment: I believe that this is the only way to do it, since the SDK is no longer going to include a copy of the compiler. Oh well, at least it avoids the licensing costs.

Comment: I haven't confirmed this solution all the way (creating a fresh Jenkins slave), but the folder that was missing is created during the VS2012 Express installation so the chance that this solution will work is high. Thanks for the help!