# Downloading build tools for VS 2012 without installing VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build-tools

I have a vc++ code which i am trying to compile in VS 2013 but its giving me error

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2012 (Platform Toolset = 'v110') cannot be found.
To build using the v110 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2012 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".
```

So i would like to know whether there is any tool that i need to Install without actually installing VS 2012

Comment: Or change the platform toolset in the project to `'v120'`.

Comment: No i would be more interested in downloading the tools.Please let me know if there is any link to download

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PlatformToolset v110 without installing Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333340/installing-platformtoolset-v110-without-installing-visual-studio-2012)