# MSVC2012 with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

How can I install MSVC 2012 compiler having only Visual Studio 2017?

I tried installing from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515), but it is issuing an error:

> 0x81f40001 - A valid Visual Studio installation was not found.

I need MSVC 2012 due to compatibility with a lib we are using.

Comment: You're much better off using the compiler version from a shipping Platform SDK than a preview (beta quality) version.

Comment: I don't think it's a preview anymore. Our company bought the professional version: VS 15.2 (26430.6) Release.

Comment: The 2012 compiler download you linked to is a preview.

Comment: I believe your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15333340/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt oh ok, I thought you were refering to Visual Studio. I didn't really find any other compiler other that one. For now I think I'll have to install VS 2015 Community (which I know works with MSVC2012).

Comment: So it seems that the answer is that there is no way to use MSVC 2012 without VS 2012. No definitive source for that info, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 10th 2017, Visual Studio 2012 is no longer available for download without an MSDN subscription.  If you install VS2012, you can choose the "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" on Visual Studio 2012/2017 from [Project] - [Properties] - [General] - [Platform Toolset].  Make sure you select your C++ project first.